# Git PR with squash merging confusion

Tags: git, github, merge

In github settings I chose the option to `Allow squash merging`, so that a pull request from the develop branch (with several commits) becomes a single commit in the master branch.

Two things I don't understand:

1. After the PR is merged, the develop branch is still xx commits ahead of the master branch. And next time I will do a PR, those xx commits will be there even if they are already merged in the master branch. How is it possible to have the develop branch in sync with the master after a PR is merged?
2. After a PR is merged, I git pull origin master on the develop branch and continue to work. It creates a merge commit, while it's exactly the same content. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to both issues is not to work with a single `develop` branch.

For each fix/feature you are working on - create a new branch.
Once development is fixed, create PR, merge it to master, and drop the development branch.

For you next fix/feature - use a new branch based on the latest master.

This is the common workflow.

Comment: That is not "the common workflow".  That is *a* workflow that works for some projects.  Using it to paper over the problems with squash-merging limits options for bug-fixing and discards a lot of history. Maybe that works for OP (or maybe OP just assumes it will), but it's not a very good answer to the question asked.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger what is OP?

Comment: @FrançoisRomain - Original Poster; shorthand used to refer to the question in many Stack Overflow comments.

Comment: Ok. "a common workflow" might be a better phrasing. Of course it discards the history, but that what happens when you squash.

Answer (score 1):

1.Before the merge, suppose `master`'s history is `A-B-C` and PR's history is `A-D-E`. After the squash-merge, `master` becomes `A-B-C-F` and PR stays unchanged. `F` includes the changes of `D` and `E`. The squash-merge doesn't combine `D` and `E` into one commit. It just creates the new commit `F` on `master`. `git log master..develop` returns `D` and `E`, so `develop` is ahead of `master` by 2 commits. The 2 commits are reachable from `develop` but not from `master`. Although the two's changes have been applied on `master`, it was done by a new commit, not by the two commits. The code will be the same by either a normal merge or a squash merge, but the history will be different. In fact, when it comes to the `A is ahead of B by n commits` thing in this case, it doesn't matter if it's a normal merge or a squash merge, as `git log master..develop` returns the same result.

2.Because `develop` and `master` are diverged, pulling `master` to `develop` brings a merge commit as expected. You could create a new PR branch from `master`. Another option is `git rebase master develop`. It moves `develop` to the commit pointed at by `master` but also makes the local `develop` diverged with the `develop` in the remote repository, so it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The symptom you describe - that `develop` is still "ahead of `master`" - is exactly the difference between a squash merge (as you've done) and a true merge.

People get excited about squash merges because when you use them, the default history no longer shows the individual commits from the merged-in branch; but (1) you can instead use things like `git log --first-parent` after a true merge to get the simplified history, and (2) squash merges are really only useful if it's the last time you'll bring changes from the target branch onto the current branch (usually because you're going to abandon the target branch).

So... how can you have the branches in sync after a PR?  By disabling squash merge.

AS for the 2nd question... merging master into your branch is exactly what `git pull master` means.  If you want to avoid that, what is the intended effect of running the command?  I mean, you can avoid the merge by not running the `pull` command, but without knowing what you intended the `pull` to do I can't say what you should run instead.